Lower bound of KL divergence of Gaussian mixture with Gaussian (univariate)
I'm interested in a non-zero Kullback-Leibler divergence lower bound between a Gaussian mixture $q$ and a standard Gaussian $p(x) = \mathcal N(x \mid 0,1)$, both univariate: $D_{KL}(q \parallel p)$. I'm aware of this question, but I conjecture that with some constraints the problem might become easier. My constraints:

The Gaussian mixture is guaranteed to have mean zero
The Gaussian mixture is guaranteed to have variance lower bounded by $\gamma^2$.

I skim over Hershey & Olsen (2007), which mentions a pretty trivial Gaussian approximation of the KL divergence in Section 4, where $q$ is approximated by a Gaussian $\bar q(x) = \mathcal N(x \mid \mu, \sigma^2)$, (here, $\mu \triangleq \mathbb E_q[x] = 0, \sigma^2 \triangleq \mathbb E_q[x^2] - \mathbb E_q[x]^2 \ge \gamma^2$); and then the target KL is approximated by $D_{KL}(\bar q \parallel p)$. However, the paper says this is a poor approximation, and does not mention whether it's a bound either.
In Melbourne et al. (2018), the authors propose an upper bound on the entropy of a mixture distribution. Since $D_{KL}(q \parallel p) = -\mathbb H(q) - \mathbb E_q[\log p(x)]$, I'm able to take advantage of it, provided that I know how to upper bound the expected log density term, which is beyond my purview again.
Thank you so much!

It turns out that this is a really simple question, but I somehow didn't think of it a while ago. We may pose the lower bound problem as an constrained optimization, whose solution is the lower bound:
$$
\min_{q'} D_{KL}(q' \parallel p)\,;\quad \text{s.t. } \int q'(x)\,\mathrm dx=1,\  \mathbb E_{q'}[x] = 0,\ \mathbb E_{q'}[x^2] = \sigma^2 \ge \gamma^2\,.
$$
By letting the functional derivative of the Lagrangian w.r.t $q$ equal zero, and plugging back $q'(x) = \exp(\text{some quadratic function w.r.t } x)$ back to the constraints solving for the Lagrange multipliers, we find that the optimal $q'$ is exactly the Gaussian approximation $\bar q = \mathcal N(x \mid 0,\sigma^2)$ (see the question for its definition) of the mixture.
In conclusion, $D_{KL}(q \parallel p) \ge D_{KL}(\bar q \parallel p)$, where the r.h.s. must be greater than zero if $\gamma^2 > 1$.
EDIT: I wrote a post on this topic in detail.
